# How much DNA (or genes) do homo-sapiens and ursus arctos (brown bear) share?

Tags: genetics, dna

How much DNA (or genes) do homo-sapiens and ursus arctos (brown bear) share? There are articles online that indicate that humans share xxx% of DNA with Chimpanzees, bananas, and other assorted organisms, but I can not find how much humans share with brown bears.

Comment: These percentage measures do not make a lot of sense. Humans also share a significant number of genes with bacteria. If you want to make comparisons, you should do an extensive analysis of the whole genome. A seemingly minor change in the genome can cause a drastic change in the traits.

Comment: timetree.org is a good place to start exploring questions like this. You can put in 'human' and 'brown bear' and it will find a whole bunch of scientific literature about how related the two organisms are, and the best estimate for when they diverged. One of those papers might have a % similarity, but really all the other stuff is the interesting part.

Comment: To add to @WYSIWYG's comment, genome-wide DNA similarity is not much studied. The part that would be somewhat interesting (a rigorous full-length nucleotide-for-nucleotide comparison) is computationally and technically extremely difficult if not impossible today, and the methods that have been used in the past to get the numbers you see are both technically difficult and scientifically uninteresting. You might find mitochondrial similarity, or similarity over a few genes, but you are unlikely to find an actual answer to your question, except in general terms.